# Cannot access `action.type` but can access `action` on reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I can only access `action` and not `action.type` on my reducer.
I tried to console.log(action.type) but it would give an undefined value.

```
export const INPUT_EMAIL = 'INPUT_EMAIL'
export const INPUT_PASSWORD = 'INPUT_PASSWORD'

export function inputEmail(email) {
    return {
        type: INPUT_EMAIL,
        email
    }
}

export function inputPassword(password) {
    return {
        type: INPUT_PASSWORD,
        password,
    }
}
```

```
// import { INPUT_EMAIL, INPUT_PASSWORD } from './actions';

const initialState = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
}

function loginReducers(state = initialState, action: Object) {
    console.log('zzZaction', action); <-- just found out it's existing 
    if(typeof state === 'undefined'){
        return initialState
    }
    // switch (action.type) {
    //     case INPUT_EMAIL: 
    //         return Object.assign({},state, {
    //             email: action.email
    //         })
    //     case INPUT_PASSWORD: 
    //     return Object.assign({}, state, {
    //         password: action.password,
    //     })
    //     default:
    //         return state
    // }
    return state
}


export default loginReducers;
```

```
//MAINPAGE

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './Dashboard.css';
import { inputEmail, inputPassword } from './redux/actions';
import Logo from './assets/login-logo.jpg';


class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        };
        this.store = this.props.store;

        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleEmailChange(event) { 
        this.setState({ email: event.target.value});
        this.props.inputEmail(this.state.email);       
    }

    handlePasswordChange(event) {
        this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
        this.props.inputPassword(this.state.password);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Dashboard">
                <div className="Dashboard-header">
                    <img className="Dashboard-logo" src={Logo} alt={'login-logo'} />
                    <h1 className="">Login Page</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="Dashboard-content">
                    <form className="Dashboard-loginContainer" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            Email:
                    <input type="email" value={this.state.email} name="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            Password:
                    <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log-In" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

//     return {
//         email: state.email,
//         password: state.password,
//     }
// }


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        inputEmail: (email: string) => dispatch(inputEmail(email)),
        inputPassword: (password: string) => dispatch(inputPassword(password)),
    }
};


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Comment: What does `console.log(action)` give?

Comment: it gives me this type of result : 
`zzZaction {type: "INPUT_EMAIL", email: "dg"}`
followed by 
`zzZaction undefined`

Comment: Don't use `setState` inside your onChange handler if the `email` and `password` is passed via `mapStateToProps` and updated via dispatch.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript of JavaScript?

Comment: @Fyodor Javascript

Comment: How does this work? `function loginReducers(state = initialState, action: Object)` This function signature is not valid in JS

Comment: Generate a repro in stackblitz it will be easier to debug.

Comment: @RajendranNadar https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-plq56z here it is

Comment: @GabrielleDurano just wrote you an answer! Let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
store.subscribe((loginReducers));
```

Instead of printing out your reducer-state, you are executing the reducer-function. `Subscribe` will trigger every time there's a change in your store. The action actually goes through the first time, but since you are calling loginReducers inside `subscribe`, it runs the reducer-function and returns an error `"cannot get type of undefined."`

You get this error because you try to invoke this function without any action being passed into the reducer. The subscribe just executed so fast that it gives the appearance that your initial action didn't execute.

This explains why you are able to print the action in the first`console.log()` but then get undefined from the second. The second `console.log()` comes from subscribe trying to executing `loginReducers` when no action was passed into it, returning undefined.

What you want is this:

```
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
```

Here is your updated sandbox for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zjywof

Now you shouldnt have any errors accessing the action-type.